# Считывание с файла и вывод вдругой

Tags: java

есть файл, с него надо найти и считать два рядочка, по 3 числа в каждом. этих рядочков может быть много. а потом эти числа записать в другой файл в виде таблицы (первый столбик - нумерация, второй - первый запрос поиска, третий - второй запрос поиска). как сделать запись в таблицу? хелп

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path p = Paths.get("F:\\OPTFREQ.LOG");
    Path o = Paths.get(p.getParent().toString(), "test.txt");
    if (Files.exists(p)) {
        System.out.println("File exists.");
        try (
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(o, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE));
                BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(p);) {
            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Pattern pat1=Pattern.compile("^ IR Inten.*([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*) .*$");
                Matcher m1=pat1.matcher(s);
                if (m1.matches()) {
                    System.out.println(m1.group(1));
                    out.println(s);
                }
                Pattern pat2=Pattern.compile("^ Frequencies.*([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*) .*$");
                Matcher m2=pat2.matcher(s);
                if (m2.matches()) {
                    System.out.println(m2.group(1));
                    out.println(s);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exists.");
    }
}
```